# Question about joint density function and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following density function:
>
> $f(x,y) = C.{e^{-x/2y}e^{-3y}\over y}$ if $0<x<\infty, 0<y< \infty$
>   and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Find $E(X|Y=2017)$.

I did $\int_o^\infty xC.{e^{-x/2y}e^{-3y}\over y}dx= e^{-6051}C\int_0^\infty {e^{-x\over4034}\over2017} = 2Ce^{-6051}$

If I did the integration correct, I need to find C but I couldn't figure out how to find it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find $C$ from the fact that $\iint_{x>0,y>0}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=1$. Find the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ and calculate the required expectation using this.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the solution in handwritten image and I hope it is clear and legible

[image]